# Graphql is returning the promise and not my DynamoDB data

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, graphql, aws-amplify

I am using a Graphql API to access my DynamoDB database. I am then trying to render the list of users in my app. According to the docs I should use:

```
import * as queries from './graphql/queries';

const users = await API.graphql({ query: queries.listUsers });
console.log(users);
```

However, I get an error regarding the **await**. So I removed the await key word, but `const users = API.graphql({ query: queries.listUsers });` returns the promise. This is the response:

```
Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}
```

I put my code into an async function and used the **await** keyword and still only got the **promise**. Is there a way to simply call the query and without the await and get the correct **data** instead of the **promise**? I have also been trying to use the **GraphQLResult** to get the actual result, but that isn't working, I am either getting errors or I am still getting the promise.

Answer (score 1):

using `try catch` block to handle error of the `await`
await return the promise result but after remove the await, it just return the promise, you should use `then catch` to get the result

Comment: So I created the async function, and in the try block when I do a `console.log(users)` I get the user data, but when I return users from the try block, and log that data, I get the promise again. How do I return the data?